# Update to 10.14.1 on Mac Pro 5.1 results in black screen

Tags: mac-pro, startup, gpu, mojave

I tried to update my Mac Pro 5.1 with the delta updater to 10.14.1 from 10.14. I have a Sapphire RX 580 installed.

After some minutes I saw he load screen but after that the screen turned black. I waited for over 2 hours and restarted the computer. I put my old Radeon 5770 inside and started in recovery mode.

I restored from time machine, but the screen remains black.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is "Delta Updater" ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 through system update in preferences

Comment: does it start in Safe mode ? did you reset SMC/NVRAM ?

Comment: I reinstalled from timemachine but now I don’t even get into recovery mode, safe mode, etc. (With 5770 I stalked) I get the startup chime and a grey screen when pushing command R.

Comment: and how about starting from USB

Comment: did you try external display

Comment: Apparently recovery partition disappeared. At least I was unable to start from MP’s system drive on a Mac Mini. I am currently installing Mojave on it and will see what happens.

Comment: @Buscar웃 since it is a Mac Pro I already have an external display attached.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same black screen issue on my 5,1 Mac Pro (also running a Sapphire RX 580). I tried putting back the original 5770, and after booting with that failed, I tried resetting the PRAM (power on and immediately hold Cmd-Opt-P-R until the machine restarts again) and that reset things and got the display working again.

It might have worked without swapping back to the older card first, I unfortunately didn’t try that, and I admit I hope not to find out. Thankfully it still was better than your OS reinstall, I was afraid it was headed that way.

Comment: Great to hear that in your case PRAM reset was enough.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working again. I am not sure, but the restore from timemachine process somehow destroyed the recovery partition.

I ended up doing he following:

1) put Mac Pro system HDD in a thunderbolt enclosure and attached it to a Mac Mini.

2) start up Mac Mini

3) install Mojave on Mac Pro HDD while keeping all the data on it

4) reinstall system disk into Mac Pro.

5) install 10.14.1 from full install image.